# Paging questions without new questions being added

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browsing Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107716/browsing-questions)

One of the first things I do in the morning (while eating my breakfast), is visit the SO newest unanswered questions page. I skim through, one page at a time, looking for questions I might like to answer.

The trouble is, as I am doing this, new questions are being added. This means that when I navigate to page-2, the 'stack' of questions will have grown, and the page will also include a portion of questions that I have already seen on page-1.

I would love a feature that allowed you to 'freeze' the stack and page through it without new items being added!

Comment: When you want to refresh with new questions would you prefer to do it manually?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't thought about the user experience, or how this might be presented in the UI. I don't think it is very easy! I have simply put my idea up here as a user need!

Comment: Thus demonstrating why the page listing the latest activity should be the highest page number in a list, not the lowest, meaning that inactive things stay exactly where they are.  Unfortunately this creates a huge violation of user expectations, where the first page is the *first* page, damnit!

Comment: Nice idea, but something similar was already suggested and declined.